# Load Json from asset c#

Tags: c#, json

I wanna load Json from Asset I tried the following code but it doesnt work can you see the error.

```
 public String loadJSONFromAsset(string filepath )
    {
        string json = null;
        try
        {
           // TextAsset targetFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(filepath);

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                  json = r.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return json;

        }
        catch  (IOException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + e.Message);
        }

        return json;
    }
```

Comment: What does the debugger say? Do you get an error?

Comment: Also maybe you could add an if statement to check if the file exists before doing stuff with it

Comment: it returns a json null. I made sure the file exists.

Comment: @hedia we need more information. Give us errors, etc.

Comment: Just for the record, there is nothing related to json / json issues as far as the code snippet goes. All you are doing is trying to read from a file. You will only start dealing with json the moment you try to deserialize it, using one of the json nuget packages available.

Comment: You might find it easier to use [File.ReadAllText(filepath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)